# Opening PowerPoint from Excel

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I'm attempting to open a PowerPoint presentation from an Excel file using a macro. I am using the following code:

```
Private Sub testButton_Click()
    Dim objPPT                               As Object
    Set objPPT = CreateObject("PowerPoint.application")
    objPPT.Visible = True
    objPPT.Activate
    objPPT.Presentations.Open (CStr(ActiveWorkbook.Path) + "\DailyHealthCheck9_24_15.ppt")
End Sub
```

but I am getting the following run-time error:

[image]

PowerPoint starts but it will not open the file. I've checked the file path and it is correct.

Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Maybe its some type of protection on the PowerPoint file.

Comment: Do you just want to open the file or do you want to be able to work with the files from your VBA code?

Comment: I have two Excel charts in the PowerPoint I would like to update with data from the Excel when macro is run.

Comment: Ok, I was just checking because if you simply wanted to open the powerpoint file there is another way.

Comment: Your path or filename must be incorrect. Is the file a ppt for sure. Is it not a pptx?

Comment: Ha, that was it. Thanks! If you post the solution I'll accept.

Comment: As an aside, in this line:  objPPT.Presentations.Open (CStr(ActiveWorkbook.Path) + "\DailyHealthCheck9_24_15.ppt") using Cstr on the path makes no sense; it's already a string, so CStr isn't needed.  And as a general practice, use & to concatenate strings rather than +

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your path or filename must be incorrect. Is the file a ppt for sure. Is it not a pptx?

Change the open line to

```
objPPT.Presentations.Open ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\DailyHealthCheck9_24_15.pptx"
```